# jQuery event listener not working on custom html tags

Tags: jquery, events

```
$('.wrapper-main' ).on('click','.itemclass',function(ev){ 
    arg.callback( this );
});
```

this function is not working for dynamically added elements whose parent is custom html tag (`<header></header>`).
items which are under valid html tag are working fine.
main selector as far as i'm aware doesn't make any difference.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/LktLexj4/ <- works fine ?

Comment: not for dynamically added elements

Comment: can you show us your html sample?, may be the problem is there

Comment: It does in the fiddle, the element is added after the event is bound. Maybe you're misunderstanding, `.wrapper-main` can't be inserted dynamically.

Comment: wow it works, unfortunately not in my code. changing to valid tag works. probably something is killing that event.

Comment: some fancy eyecandy js effect is messing with event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind element with event:

```
$('.wrapper-main').bind('click',function(ev){
 arg.callback( this );
});
```

Or:

```
$('.item-class').bind('click',function(ev){
 arg.callback( this );
});
```

Comment: `bind` was replaced by `on` a **few years** back ?

Comment: I didn't know about it. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

To attach a handler to a dynamically added element, you must bind to an element that is on the page at the time of binding and will be a parent of the dynamically added element. Most often you will see `$(document).on('event', 'dynamical element, handler)`